# Filter out objects in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and not very familiar with SQL either.
I have a Django model that describes a person and has all sorts of fields, two of them are

1. country
2. race_time

I want to be able to filter out all of the objects and leave only the fastest persons with the best race_time, 1 person per 1 country.

How can I do that with Django filtering?

Comment: use distinct with `country` and order by `race_time` or `-race_time` depends on whatever order you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach as Hemal said is the following:

```
YourObject.objects.order_by('country', 'race_time').distinct('country')
```

The reason for this syntax is that:

> When you specify field names, you must provide an order_by() in the QuerySet, and the fields in order_by() must start with the fields in distinct(), in the same order.

For more details you can check out [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) docs.

Comment: how about ordering by something that isn't a number? 
like order by this 
"FIRST" > "SECOND" ?
how can I do it with manual gt/lt method?

Comment: Can you add a little more details? I cant quite understand what you mean by first > second